# JS: How Can I Convert HTML Element Into A PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, download

I need to download This HTML & CSS page as **PDF**. When User Click this Button

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
```

```css
table{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pdf_content">
<center><h1>Customers</h1></center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Test01</td>
      <td>+44712365478</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>  
</div>
<br>
<button>Download PDF</button>
```

Is there any Plugins or Functions for **This**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the jQuery and [jsPDF Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf):

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Instantiate jsPDF class:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

Retrieve the HTML content from the specific element by ID or class.
Convert HTML content of the specific part of the web page and generate PDF.
Save and download the HTML content as a PDF file.

Comment: Do jsPDF needs JQuery

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to convert to PDF directly. You can call `window.print()` however, which will open the print dialog of the user's browser.
On most modern systems, there is a PDF printer preinstalled.